# Kubernetes pod running via MicrosK8s on Ubuntu OS on a GCE VM on google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run google cloud python sdk from inside a k8 pod, running on google compute engine. There is a service account attached to the VM, which is giving it access to the secrets manager. I am able to access secrets manager from the host, however running the python sdk from k8 pod complains of not able to access the metadata service

```
>>> secret_id = 'unskript_test'
>>> name = client.secret_path(project_id, secret_id)
>>> response = client.get_secret(request={"name": name})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1630634901.103779641","description":"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable","file":"src/core/lib/security/credentials/plugin/plugin_credentials.cc","file_line":90,"grpc_status":14}"
>
```

metadata.google.internal doesnt get resolved from the k8 pod

```
jovyan@jovyan-25ca6c8c-157d-49e5-9366-f9d57fcb7a9f:~$ wget http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
--2021-09-03 02:11:19--  http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
Resolving metadata.google.internal (metadata.google.internal)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘metadata.google.internal’
```

However, host is able to resolve it

```
ubuntu@gcp-test-proxy:~$ wget http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
--2021-09-03 02:11:27--  http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
Resolving metadata.google.internal (metadata.google.internal)... 169.254.169.254
Connecting to metadata.google.internal (metadata.google.internal)|169.254.169.254|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-09-03 02:11:27 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

How can i make the pod resolve metadata.google.internal?

Comment: Could it be that you need to enable DNS on MicroK8s? https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-dns. Another test would be to confirm that you can `curl` (or `wget`) the Metadata service from within a pod using the Metadata service's IP (`169.254.169.254` port 80)

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin. dns is enabled on microk8s
```
ubuntu@gcp-test-proxy:~$ microk8s status
microk8s is running
high-availability: no
  datastore master nodes: 127.0.0.1:19001
  datastore standby nodes: none
addons:
  enabled:
    dashboard            # The Kubernetes dashboard
    dns                  # CoreDNS
```

i have tried the wget as i put in my question above, from both pod as well as host. Pod doesnt resolve it. Here is the pod /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Defaulting container name to vpn.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/enterprise-gateway-68fd8684d5-tlczw -n eg' to see all of the containers in this pod.
search eg.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local us-west1-b.c.unskript-test.internal c.unskript-test.internal google.internal
nameserver 10.152.183.10
options ndots:5

Comment: oh i was able to wget using the IP. So i added the /etc/hosts entry to make it work.

169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal

However, the issue for me is the pod where i am running the cloud sdk is ephemeral, so i cant do this manual edit there. 
I dont think i am the first one trying this out, so wanted to know if i am missing something basic here?

Comment: So I think the issue is that the cluster's (CoreDNS) not using the host for DNS resolution.

Comment: yes, is there a config to enable that?

Comment: See: https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-dns and then https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/3043#issuecomment-514725706 I've not done it but I suspect you want to a server block for `google.internal`.

Comment: I've provided as much help as I'm able. I'm about to create a GKE (!) cluster and will check its Metadata service resolution. If I learn anything useful, I'll add a comment here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dazwilkin. It’s an issue with microk8s, things work fine with minikube

Comment: @Amit   As per your comment issue got resolved ,  it would be great if you post an answer detailing the steps you have followed .

Comment: @Rameshkollisetty, the issue is not resolved with microk8s, i am tracking an issue with them https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/2555.
We moved to using minikube for now.